# I have some random letters at the top of my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

Over the past few days I have had a small problem with my word press website. The problem is that i seem to have lots of random Ns and Ts at the top of each page. An example of this is shown in the image below. 
http://prntscr.com/66bihd

If anyone has any ideas what is going on here that would be great, I have a feeling it is something to do with a header file? 
This is the header.php file http://pastebin.com/aivJLVmj

Comment: You may want to add the contents of your header.php file to your question.

Comment: Will it be alright in a paste bin link? also i might change a few thngs like links in there aswell

Comment: Yep, but change as little as you can.

Comment: @danbahrami i have added the header.php for you

Comment: Wowsers that is a big header file!!! I have seen the issue and will put it in an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header file is full of instances of `echo "nt"` and similar things.

`echo` is PHP for output the following onto the page.

I have amended your pastbin to remove all of the strange bits [here](http://pastebin.com/0k017qVA)

Regards

Dan

Comment: Thanks very much it works perfect now, also my site is much faster]

Comment: You're welcome however my amendments should have made negligible difference to your load times. Just some friendly advice: Judging from your header I would say that your theme is massively bloated and if possible look at getting a better theme with fewer 'bonus features'. that will go a long way to increasing the speed of your site.

Comment: Ah ok thank you for the advice, dont suppose you also know how to redirect users if they are not logged into my site without getting redirect loop problems?

Comment: You should file this as a separate question and I'll be glad to help. When you do add some specifics... why do you want to redirect them and from what page to what page etc.

Comment: Okay doing this now, thanks for your help , i just need this question setting as closed now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569412/how-do-i-redirect-non-logged-in-users-wordpress Thats my new question dan :) I made a new proper account now