# How do i redirect non logged in users Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, file, wordpress-theming

I am looking to redirect users who are not logged in on any page of my WordPress website to a /welcome page which will have a sign up form on. This is pretty essential as it is a small social networking site.

I am also trying to do this without having any redirect loop issues so my users can easily get to the /welcome page without any hassle.

Comment: @danbahrami I have a new account as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your `header.php` file

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_page( 'welcome' ) ) {

    wp_redirect( bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/welcome' );
    exit;

}
```

Hope that helps

Regards

Dan

Comment: Where abouts is the best place to put it because if it put it at the top i just get the code on my website at the top?

Comment: Sorry but did you see my comment?

Comment: Got it to work, also is this supposed to work on mobile as well or just desktop?

Comment: @ThePhotoChest glad you got it to work. this should work on mobiles too.

Comment: No it just seems to be coming up with to many redirect loops on phones but it works perfectly on the desktop

Comment: ok @danbahrami i have fixed the mobile issues now, but lastly ive just thought of somthing cool, is there any way to add another page to the list which dont redirect users to the welcome page as i want users t be able to acsess the /welcome page and the /sign-up page

Comment: @ThePhotoChest could you share on how you got it working on mobiles and what the issue was? You just add && !is_page( 'the-slug-of-your-page') to the end of the if statement.

Comment: Tbh i didnt do much to get it to work on mobile i just updated the files and changed the !is_page( 'welcome' ) to another page updated changed it back and it seemed to work fine. Also as i already have if( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_page( 'welcome' ) ) { how do i add the other page i dont want to redirect onto that?

Comment: it should be `get_bloginfo(` not `bloginfo(`